# How do you correctly pass a pointer between calls with Python C-API

Tags: python, c, cpython

I'm writing a python + c module, and I'm trying to pass a pointer to a certain struct I need. I'm using PyCapsule to encapsulate the pointer, but I'm having problems when retrieving the pointer from it.
The C functions used are like:

```
static PyObject *
spam_new (PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    unsigned int number;
    struct spam *pointer;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "I", &number)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    
    state = (struct spam*) malloc(sizeof (struct spam));
    if (state == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    spam_init(*pointer, number);
    return PyCapsule_New((void*) pointer, "spam", &spam_destroy);
}

static PyObject *
spam_get (PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *capsule, *result;
    void *raw_pointer;
    struct spam *pointer;
    unsigned long long int number;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OK", capsule, &number)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    printf("[DEBUG] Number: %llu\n", number);
    printf("[DEBUG] Capsule pointer: %p\n", capsule);
    raw_pointer = PyCapsule_GetPointer(capsule, "spam");
    if (raw_pointer == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    pointer = (struct spam*) raw_pointer;
    
    .
    .
    .
}
```

They are both declared with METH_VARARGS.
When in python, custom.new(1) returns a capsule as expected, which I store in a variable *c*.
When calling custom.get(c, 14) python crashes at the PyCapsule_GetPointer function call. Both prints show the same (14), meaning that PyArg_ParseTuple is not getting the capsule passed as a parameter.

For security reasons passing the pointer as a *long* is not an option.

Thanks.

Comment: That call to `PyArg_ParseTuple` can’t modify `capsule`; how did this build without uninitialized-variable warnings?

Comment: I don't know, but it is not throwing any warnings. It does modify capsule to the same value as the other argument (pointing to memory address 0x00...0014

Comment: It doesn't modify `capsule`, because you didn't take its address.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#other-objects) is stated that the "O" format string will try to get a pointer to a PyObject (a PyObject*), not a PyObject.

Therefore when using `PyArg_ParseTuple` to get a PyObject* you have to pass a pointer to a PyObject*.

The provided code was fixed by adding a & to the capsule in the line

`if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OK", &capsule, &number)) {`

Fixed thanks to [Davis Herring](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8586227/davis-herring)'s comment.